# NotebookAutoSave -> True "partially" working?

Tags: notebooks, options

I am a novice to *Mathematica* (using v10.2) and was wondering why:

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave -> True]
```

does not switch on `Autosave` when I check in `Global Preferences -> File Options`? It works in that my works is autosaved but it does not check as true under file options.

Any help would be really appreciated.

PS I found this command: `CurrentValue[FrontEnd, "NotebookAutoSave"] = True` which does turn `Autosave` as true and does the job but as a newbie to *Mathematica* I don't know why this is the case. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Welcome!   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks for the overview. Hope someone answers this one.

Comment: With the code you used it is not a global setting, but just for the selected notebook (there is a drop down menu in the options inspector to look at that specifically)

Comment: Yeah I thought of it through the night and arrived at a similar conclusion but thank you for backing up my conjecture. Really appreciated.